# Server Error when adding table to doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've got a Google Apps Script that pulls some data from a couple places and assembles it into a Google Doc in a specific format.  Part of the format is a table with some styling that varies from cell to cell.  Everything was working fine, until some of the data included new lines.  My scripts started failing with the very helpful message "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

I've gone through and stripped out every bit of extraneous code I can fine, and here's what I've got:

```
function executeBugTest(){

  var problemString = "1\n12";

  var style = {}; 
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = "#000000";

  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();
  var table = body.appendTable();

  var tableRow = table.appendTableRow();
  tableRow.appendTableCell().setAttributes(style);
  tableRow.appendTableCell(problemString);
  // error on the next line
  tableRow.appendTableCell();


};
```

Here's all the conditions that I've figured out that are required to cause the error:

- `problemString` must contain a new line
- `problemString` must be at least 4 characters (counting the new line)
- `style` must set *something* (it doesn't seem to matter what)

Unfortunately, those are all requirements :[.

Here's everything that I've tried that doesn't seem to affect the error:

- position of the table on the page
- content before the table
- additional rows in the same table
- additional columns in the same table
- additional calls to setAttributes() in the same table

Any ideas on what's going on here?  I'll keep experimenting and looking for alternate way of constructing this table, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. From my own experience and as you demonstrate, the problem is caused by the `'\n'` in your problemString.

I do not have a *"clean"* solution, but I do have a workaround that only requires one extra line.

I use placeholder text when appending the cell and the use the `replaceText()` function to insert the problem string. I will use your code block (minus the style changes) to demonstrate the workaround.

```
function executeBugTest(){

var problemString = "1\n12";

var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = document.getBody();
var table = body.appendTable();

var tableRow = table.appendTableRow();
var cell1 = tableRow.appendTableCell("PlaceholderText");
var cell2 = tableRow.appendTableCell("Other Text);

cell1.replaceText("PlaceholderText", problemString);

};
```

Hope this works for you :)